# How to get start time and end time in fullCalendar in angularJs

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar

I am doing event scheduler application using fullcalendar and angularJs.
Here i am getting all the out put except start time and end time in week agenda.
How can i get start and end time in calendar.

```
var myApp = angular.module('calenderApp', ['ui']);
myApp.controller('calenderCtrl', ['$scope', '$http' ,function($scope, $http)
{
getInfo();
function getInfo() 
{
    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();
$scope.uiConfig = {
      calendar:{
        defaultView: 'agendaDay',
        height: 450,
        firstDay: 1,
        weekends:false,
        editable: true,
        header:{
          left: 'title',
          center: 'month',
          right: 'today prev,next'
        },
        ignoreTimezone: false,
        dayClick: $scope.alertEventOnClick,
        eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
        eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize
      }
    };
    $http.post("http://localhost/AdminLTE-master/sism_crm/route/campaign/campaign/calendar").then(function(response) {
    $scope.events = response.data;
    var length=response.data.length;
    for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
     {
         $scope.eventSources.push({
            idx: response.data[i].idx,
            title: response.data[i].title,
            description : response.data[i].description,
            allDay: true,
            start: new Date(response.data[i].start), 
            end:  new Date(response.data[i].end),
            startTime:  new Date(response.data[i].startTime),
            endTime:  new Date(response.data[i].endTime),
            });
            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents'); 
      }
    });   
}
}]);
```

How can get start time and end time in calendar.thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 0):

Use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) with the following piece of code:

```
moment(event.start).format('h:mm:ss');
```

This works for me as I wanted the time in the event object on click.